# Merge continuous intervals among group_by()

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have an issue with some data and am looking for your help.
Here is a subset of a larger dataset with thousands of vessels:

```
subset <- tibble::tribble(
           ~cfr, ~vessel_name, ~reg_port, ~event_start_date, ~event_end_date, ~length, ~tonnage, ~power,                     ~gear,         ~gear_cat,      ~gear_type,
 "FRA000859026",   "PATOLISA",      "ST",      "1995-04-10",    "1996-09-06",    7.25,     3.02,    110, "Set gillnets (anchored)", "Entangling nets", "Passive gears",
 "FRA000859026",   "PATOLISA",      "ST",      "1996-09-07",    "1996-12-31",    7.25,     3.02,     85, "Set gillnets (anchored)", "Entangling nets", "Passive gears",
 "FRA000859026",   "PATOLISA",      "ST",      "1997-01-01",    "1999-12-01",    7.25,     3.02,     85, "Set gillnets (anchored)", "Entangling nets", "Passive gears",
 "FRA000859026",   "PATOLISA",      "ST",      "1999-12-02",    "2000-02-03",    7.25,     3.02,     85, "Set gillnets (anchored)", "Entangling nets", "Passive gears",
 "FRA000859026",   "PATOLISA",      "ST",      "2000-02-04",    "2001-06-10",    7.25,     3.02,    110, "Set gillnets (anchored)", "Entangling nets", "Passive gears",
 "FRA000859026",   "PATOLISA",      "ST",      "2001-06-11",    "2001-07-23",    7.25,     3.02,    110, "Set gillnets (anchored)", "Entangling nets", "Passive gears",
 "FRA000859026",   "PATOLISA",      "ST",      "2001-07-24",    "2002-12-31",    7.25,     3.02,    110, "Set gillnets (anchored)", "Entangling nets", "Passive gears",
 "FRA000859026",   "PATOLISA",      "ST",      "2003-01-01",    "2004-03-10",    7.25,     3.02,    110, "Set gillnets (anchored)", "Entangling nets", "Passive gears"
 )
```

I want to simplify these data so as to have continuous intervals (`event_start_date` -> `event_end_date`) for each group of similar `cfr`, `vessel_name`, `reg_port`, `length`, `tonnage`, `power`, `gear`, `gear_cat`, and `gear_type`. My expected results look like this:

```
~cfr, ~vessel_name, ~reg_port, ~event_start_date, ~event_end_date, ~length, ~tonnage, ~power,                     ~gear,         ~gear_cat,      ~gear_type,
 "FRA000859026",   "PATOLISA",      "ST",      "1995-04-10",    "1996-09-06",    7.25,     3.02,    110, "Set gillnets (anchored)", "Entangling nets", "Passive gears",
 "FRA000859026",   "PATOLISA",      "ST",      "1996-09-07",    "2000-02-03",    7.25,     3.02,     85, "Set gillnets (anchored)", "Entangling nets", "Passive gears",
 "FRA000859026",   "PATOLISA",      "ST",      "2000-02-04",    "2004-03-10",    7.25,     3.02,    110, "Set gillnets (anchored)", "Entangling nets", "Passive gears"
 )
```

However, no matter what I try, my results always combine all records with power = 110 even though there is an interval in between with power = 85.

In particular, I've tried a couple of things, which do not work as expected:

**1. group_by() and mutate()**

```
subset %>%
  group_by(cfr, vessel_name, reg_port, length, tonnage, power, gear, gear_cat, gear_type) %>%
  mutate(event_start_date = min(event_start_date), #Find oldest date for group
           event_end_date = max(event_end_date)) %>% #Find most recent date for group
    ungroup() %>%
    distinct()
```

==> All records with power = 110 are considered similar, which creates two silly overlapping records, one for power = 110 from 1995-04-10 to 2004-03-10, and one with power = 85 from 1996-09-07 to 2000-02-03

**2. cur_group_id()**

So I thought it would make sense to create a sequential `id` for each group, so that I could then do a similar mutate() but this time using `id` in my grouping. I tried to use cur_group_id(), but the result is the same: all records with power = 110 are considered similar, even though I do want to separate the two chronological groups.

```
subset %>%
  group_by(cfr, vessel_name, reg_port, length, tonnage, power, gear, gear_cat, gear_type) %>%
  mutate(id = cur_group_id()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(event_start_date = min(event_start_date), #Find oldest date for group
           event_end_date = max(event_end_date)) %>% #Find most recent date for group
    ungroup() %>%
    distinct()
```

How can I ensure that this does not happen and that I get my expected output, i.e. intervals merged by group BUT accounting for chronological changes? This is probably very simple but can't wrap my head around it...

Thanks!

Comment: In your subset data frame row 2 to 4 all have power 85 but the start and end dates are continuous. I wanna ask are there any rows in your original data frame with the same intervals but powers equal to 110? Otherwise the interruption is inevitable.

Comment: No, each row corresponds to a change in one of the columns, so there shouldn't be similar intervals for the same vessels but with different parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `data.table` and `rleid`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(subset)


subset[,.(event_start_date = min(event_start_date),
          event_end_date   = max(event_end_date)),
       by=.(rleid(cfr, vessel_name, reg_port, length, tonnage, power,gear, gear_cat, gear_type ),
            cfr,
            vessel_name,
            reg_port,
            length,
            tonnage,
            power,
            gear,
            gear_cat,
            gear_type)]

            cfr vessel_name reg_port length tonnage power rleid                    gear        gear_cat     gear_type event_start_date event_end_date
1: FRA000859026    PATOLISA       ST   7.25    3.02   110     1 Set gillnets (anchored) Entangling nets Passive gears       1995-04-10     1996-09-06
2: FRA000859026    PATOLISA       ST   7.25    3.02    85     2 Set gillnets (anchored) Entangling nets Passive gears       1996-09-07     2000-02-03
3: FRA000859026    PATOLISA       ST   7.25    3.02   110     3 Set gillnets (anchored) Entangling nets Passive gears       2000-02-04     2004-03-10
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks great and I will look into it! I wanted to avoid data.table, which I do not know at all, but will certainly use it if necessary :)

Comment: Hmm... not as perfect as I thought :(
Your solution accounts for changes in `power`, but what if `length` or `tonnage` changes instead, or `gear`? For instance, there will probably be records where `length`, `tonnage`, and `power` will not change, while `reg_port` or `gear` will change... is it possible to have a generic code so that similar *and* chronological chunks are merged?

Comment: rleid can be used with multiple columns, see my edit

Comment: Oh wow! I might start looking into data.table ;)
Thanks for the massive help Waldi!